# Popup image after clicking submit

Tags: javascript, forms, submit

So I have a form with an image for a submit button:

```
<input type="image" src="assets/sendemail.png" name="submit" value="submit">
```

So what I need is to when I press the submit image, an image I have will popup saying that the comment has been sent, then I can press OK and go back.

Answer (score 0):

Looking for a jQuery UI Dialog?

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Answer (score 0):

your input needs an id or class.
you could use jQuery to handle the event and display that image with css:

```
$('#idforinput').click(function(){
    $('#yourcontainer).css("visibility","visible");
});
```